# how to find a word in one sentence using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have this sample data:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Re: Krishna P Mohan (31231231 / NA0031212301)
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
```

This is what I expect and currently get:

> expected op - Krishna P Mohan
>
> output - Krishna P Mohan (31231231 / NA0031212301)

I need to find the name which is comes after the Re: and till the (. im getting the complete line instead of only name till bracket starts.

#### code

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[\n\r].*Re:\s*([^\n\r]*)");
var fullNameText = regex.Match(extractedDocContent).Value;
```

Comment: You can excude matching the parenthesis `\bRe:\s*([^\n\r(]*)`

Comment: May be use `^\s*Re:\s*([^()]+?)\s*\(` in multiline mode

Comment: @Thefourthbird im getting match like this - Re: Krishna P Mohan. how to exclude Re:

Comment: You can take the group 1 value, if you want a match only then `(?<=\bRe:\s*)[^\n\r()]*[^\s()]` https://regex101.com/r/ZLFP5Y/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a match only, you can use a lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=\bRe:\s*)[^\s()]+(?:[^\n\r()]*[^\s()])?
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\bRe:\s*)` Positive lookbehind, assert the word `Re:` followed by optional whitespace chars to the left
- `[^\s()]+` Match 1 or more non whitespace chars except for `(` and `)`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\n\r()]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except newlines and `(` or `)`
  - `[^\s()]`  Match a non whitespace character except for `(` and `)`
- `)?` Close the non capture group

If you want the capture group value, and you are matching only word characters:

```
\bRe:\s*([^\n\r(]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p6inSt/1)

Else you can use:

```
\bRe:\s*([^\s()]+(?:[^\n\r()]*[^\s()])?)
```

Comment: this regex is not working. i need text between Re: and (. if it contains Re: and ( then it should extract.

Comment: @krishnamohan The pattern is working for the example data and the value is in the capture group 1 value. Can you create a regex101 example with the data that you want to match?

Comment: @krishnamohan Else use `(?<=\bRe:\s*)[^\s()](?:[^\n\r()]*[^\s()])?` See https://regex101.com/r/tpUQhb/1 And f there has to be a `(` present then `(?<=\bRe:\s*)[^\s()](?:[^\n\r()]*[^\s()])?(?=\s*\()` https://regex101.com/r/xAGAkq/1

Comment: @krishnamohan The second patten will do that, see https://regex101.com/r/lBLT3i/1